# Having error in contribution page after upgrade to 4.7.29

Tags: payment-processor, contribution-page

I'm a civicrm user, and I have problrm with contribution page after upgrade to 4.7.29, My civicrm installed on Joomla 3.8.3, this error show when I open the contribution form from frontsite.

the error message is :
Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ablecomm/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php on line 59

I have been trying to fix this but no have idea where is the problem.

is Anybody can help me?
thankyou

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug and is documented and fixed at [CRM-21595](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21595).  You will need to apply the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11454/files) to fix the problem or will need to wait for 4.7.30 release.